# Nested hash map in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap

I'm trying to create a **nested hash map** in **js** like in the example below:

```
let rooms = {};

rooms[roomNum][personName] = somethings
```

the problem is that when I try to do that I recive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'personName' of undefined
```

I'm able to create just a "***one level hash map***" like that `rooms[roomNum] = somethings`

Answer (score 2):

1. That's not a hashmap, it's an object
2. `rooms[roomNum]` is not defined so you can't add something to `rooms[roomNum][personName]`

Here is an example on how you can do what you want to do:

```
let rooms = {};
rooms[roomNum] = {};
rooms[roomNum][personName] = somethings;
```